# How do we know that the Fourier transform of space is momentum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, waves, fourier-transform

How do we know that the Fourier transform of real space $x$ is the momentum $p$ space or for energy and time, receptively? 
What's the mathematical process and physical logic?

Comment: Have you read the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position_and_momentum_space

Comment: yes. nothing intuitive there. did you find something useful?

Comment: i found some good sentences there (although not strict):The momentum representation of a wave function is very closely related to the Fourier transform and the concept of frequency domain. Since a quantum mechanical particle has a frequency proportional to the momentum (de Broglie's equation given above), describing the particle as a sum of its momentum components is equivalent to describing it as a sum of frequency components (i.e. a Fourier transform). This becomes clear when we ask ourselves how we can transform from one representation to another.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What's the mathematical process and physical logic?

The Fourier transform of position space ($\vec x$ domain) is wave number space ($\vec k$ domain).  This is an unambiguous, well understood mathematical result.

By the De Broglie hypothesis, the momentum is $\vec p = \hbar \vec k$.  This is physical hypothesis with [experimental confirmation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave#Experimental_confirmation).

Although the above answers the quoted question, I suspect that you won't find it satisfying as you're looking for something 'deeper'.  In that case, think carefully about what your actual question is and post it as a separate question.

For example, "what is the physical intuition that motivates the De Broglie hypothesis"?  I haven't searched but that question may already have an answer here.

Comment: "The Fourier transform of position space (x⃗  domain) is wave number space (k⃗  domain). This is an unambiguous, well understood mathematical result." How is it clearly understood? what makes it to be clear?

Comment: @P.A.M, I don't understand your question.  What do you mean by "how" and "what" makes it clearly understood?  Would the fact that the spatial Fourier transform underlies almost all image processing give one reason to believe that it is well understood?  See, for example, https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/courses/compsci773s1c/lectures/ImageProcessing-html/topic1.htm

Comment: I'm afraid you've completely left out the crux of the issue: how any point in wave-number space can have anything to do with momentum, given that it inverse-Fourier-transforms back to a static function in position space. What you left out is that these functions represent only phasors, and the actual matter waves underlying the phasor functions are not static but always traveling at phase velocity ħk/(2m), so they carry momentum proportional to wave-number.

Answer (score 2):

To quantize a classical system, start from the Poisson bracket $$\{x_i, p_j\} = \delta_{ij}.$$
This relation defines $p_i$ as the *momentum canonically conjugate to $x_i$* and is equivalent to Hamilton's equations. Quantize by letting $x_i, p_j$ be Hermitian operators on a Hilbert space, with commutator $$[\hat x_i, \hat p_j] = i\delta_{ij} $$ (identity operator implicit). Let $|\vec x\rangle$ denote an eigenstate with eigenvalues $\vec x$ and $\psi(\vec x) = \langle \vec x | \psi \rangle$. Then the operator $$\hat p_i : |\psi\rangle  \mapsto -i \int d^3x' |\vec x\rangle \frac{\partial }{\partial \vec x_i} \psi(\vec x)$$
satisfies the commutation relation ([and is the only such operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem)). With this representation of the momentum operator, the eigenvalue problem is $$\langle \vec x'| \hat p_i |\psi\rangle =\vec p_i\langle x'|\psi\rangle = \vec p_i \psi(x') = -i\int d^3\vec x\,  \delta(\vec x-\vec x') \frac{\partial}{\partial \vec x_i} \psi(\vec x)$$
or using the Dirac delta,
$$p_i \psi(x) = -i\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec x_i}\psi(x).$$
Thus, for an eigenstate of momentum, $\psi(x) \propto e^{\vec p\cdot \vec x}$. That is, the state is a plane wave.

To summarize, from the canonical Poisson brackets, quantized to the canonical commutation relations, we find that momentum eigenstates are plane waves. Thus expressing a problem in terms of momentum eigenstates is the same as expressing it in plane waves, which is precisely what the Fourier transform does.

Answer (score 2):

In the book of Kreyszig, Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications, page 577, there is the following reasoning to associate momentum with Fourier frequency. It would be interesting to discuss if it is correct:

Using Einstein's mass-energy relation $E= mc^2$, and Planck equation $E= h\nu$ ($\nu$=frequency), we can write the momentum

$p= mc = E/c = h\nu/c = h/\lambda$

where $\lambda = c/\nu$ is the wavelength. Hence wavelength and momentum are related by

$1/\lambda = p/h$.

A plane wave of length $\lambda$ (or momentum $p$) is given by

$\exp(2\pi i x/\lambda) = \exp(2\pi i xp/h),$

so the Fourier inversion formula
$$
\psi(x) = \int \hat\psi(\xi)\exp(2\pi i x\cdot\xi)\,d\xi
= \frac1h\,\int \hat\psi(p/h)\exp(2\pi i x\cdot p/h)\,dp
$$
gives a decomposition of $\psi(x)$ in terms of plane waves of momentum $p$.
The quantity $|\hat\psi(p/h)|$ describes the amplitude at momentum $p$.
So, if $|\psi(x)|^2dx$ is the probability density of the position in state $\psi$, then by Plancherel theorem $|\hat\psi(p/h)|^2dp/h$ should be the probability density of momentum in state $\psi$.

Finally, the mean value of momentum can be written as
$$
\mu_p=\int p|\hat\psi(p/h)|^2dp/h = h\int \xi \hat\psi(\xi){\overline{\hat\psi(\xi)}}\,d\xi= \frac{h}{2\pi i}\int \psi'\,\bar\psi=\langle P\psi,\psi\rangle,$$
if we define the momentum operator $P$ by
$$P\psi=\frac{h}{2\pi i}\frac{d}{dx}\psi.$$

Answer (score 1):

A Fourier transform is the decomposition of a position space function into a basis of plane waves, each of which has a well defined momentum.

$$
f(x) \sim \int \text{d}p\; F(p) e^{\text{i}px}
$$

This relies on the quantum mechanical idea that waves can have a well defined momentum.

Comment: It's makes the statement of the question changed and doesn't answer the why and how!

Comment: The Fourier transform is a well defined mathematical operation. Transforming basis from position to momentum in wave mechanics has the same form as a Fourier transform.

Comment: why not the position and something else? what makes them to be conjugate?

Comment: I think there's something really deep behind that because position and momentum appear as conjugate variables in many situations. But at the very least, it has to be that way given the axioms of quantum mechanics.

Comment: Maybe one insight is that a plane wave (which you could consider a basic building block of a wave mechanical theory) has momentum and position in a conjugate relationship i.e. $e^{ipx}$.

Comment: Actually you should consider exp(ikx). Then connect wave number and momentum using quantum mechanics.

Comment: why should it have the position and momentum in it's building block? that's a restating again!?!

Comment: There's a lot of empirical evidence motivating the ideas of wave mechanics. In the end, our physical theories are motivated by the empirical evidence we have experience with.

Comment: I suspect you're trying to find an answer to an ill-posed question...

Comment: I think the fundamental question here is why we can identify momentum with spatial frequency.

Comment: then as you say:" why we can identify momentum with spatial frequency"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19503/discussion-between-bdforbes-and-p-a-m).